# Prepared statement with dynamic where clause

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I have a search page with multiple search criteria

1. Employee Name
2. Employee Id
3. Date of joining
4. Department

etc

User can provide one or more search criteria. I need to query database to get the search results.

Using plain JDBC, there are two options to achieve this.

1. Prepare SQL query by appending search criteria provided by user.

ex:

```
String selectClause = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE ";
String whereClause = "";
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empName)){
    if(whereClause.length > 0){
        whereClause += " AND ";
    }
    selectQuery += " EMP_NAME = " + empName;
}
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empID)){
    if(whereClause.length > 0){
        whereClause += " AND ";
    }
    selectQuery += " EMP_ID = " + empID;
}
//... and so on ...
```

2. Using `preparestatement`

ex:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_NAME = ? AND EMP_ID = ? DATE_OF_JOINING = ? AND DEPARTMENT = ?";
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943738/960778) explains that like ex 1 above, ex2 can be modified, something like below

```
String selectClause = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE ";
String whereClause = "";
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empName)){
    if(whereClause.length > 0){
        whereClause += " AND ";
    }
    selectQuery += " EMP_NAME = ?";
}
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empID)){
    if(whereClause.length > 0){
        whereClause += " AND ";
    }
    selectQuery += " EMP_ID = ?";
}
//... and so on ...
```

Then carefully (keeping parameter index in mind) the input needs to set to the prepared statement. This doesn't sounds to be a very ideal solution.

Is there a way to do this in an elegant way (without ORM frameworks) ?

Comment: Your first approach can *easily* lead to SQL injection attacks if you are not extremely careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't like using a `StringBuilder` to dynamically create a query each and every time, especially when the number of meaningful combinations is countable and finite.

I'd always prefer static Strings.  Yes, you have to type them in, but you'll do that once.  I'd rather do that than pay the price in complexity and at runtime.

Comment: You mean I should have static queries ready for each combination of inputs ? Currently I have four inputs, so queries for combination of the four inputs ? Going forward there may be more inputs. Won't this complete things ?

Comment: Yes, I would type they out.  I'd say that a touch typist can bang out 10 queries without too much trouble.  All combinations aren't equally valid.  I'd say that you'd be better off thinking about the ones that users are most likely to really use and just implement them once statically as PreparedStatements.  You could probably have them coded in the time it takes to debate the answer here.

Comment: Won't it be unfair with my employer to not follow the recommended approach ?

Comment: I don't know what that comment means, and I'm not sure on whose authority the recommended approach is assumed to be best.  You owe it to yourself and your employer to produce the best application you can based on several critiria that may conflict: performance, readability, maintainability, security, etc.

Comment: I am not speaking against you or your approach. I have 100% faith in the approach suggested by you. I am trying to know and evaluate all the suggested alternatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like this is the only option for this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

In such conditions I prefer adding `1=1` in where clause so that you dont have to keep track of where to insert `AND`.

```
String selectClause = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 1=1 ";
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empName)){
   selectQuery += "AND EMP_NAME = " + empName;
}
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(empID)){
   selectQuery += "AND EMP_ID = " + empID;
}
//... and so on ...
```

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause).

Comment: Although 1=1 is a very convenient way of adding all the 'ANDs', be aware that some RDBMS engines/optimisers go bonkers and your query performance may become very bad.

I add all the conditions into an List and join them with an AND.
Something like `String whereClause = StringUtils.join(conditionsList, " AND ");`

Comment: @xyz What if we have some condition with `OR` clause also?

Comment: @Piyush then use `OR` instead of `AND` like  `selectQuery += "OR.. `

Comment: @xyz Then all conditions will become useless because  `1=1 OR some_condition` will be always `true`.

Comment: this example is vulnerable to SQL injection as mentioned in the comments above by @Bruno Reis. How would we accomplish this in an easy way using Prepared Statements?

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do without any complex or expensive logic, in a single line...

Assuming that your three variables are @name, @surname, and @gender.

Also assuming that a zero-length string will be provided when a filter is not required.

Then, your Select statement is simply:

```
    select * from table_name where (name = @name or @name = '') and (surname = @surname or @surname = '') and (gender = @gender or @gender = '')
```

That's all there is to it! No complex or expensive logic.

Comment: Is this a JDBC prepared statement ? 
What SQL is generated if name isn't a required parameter ?